# How to create a chart in oracle apex, using two dropdown box values?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

For Ex: one dropdown box value has a list of product names, other dropdown box holds the number of products etc... The graph should change based on the dropdown value selection

Comment: This is very feasible, but it would easier to assist if you can share what you have so far. Truthfully, this question is poorly formed; it shows a lack of effort. Please take the time to expand on this and I'd be happy to assist.

Comment: Like @hisnameismyname2 says, this question is no question at all. Unless I should answer "Yes". If you want us to build an application which implements all this, just as a demo, it won't really work - that's not the point of SO either. If you want charting demo's, there are plenty of them out on the internet or you can find plenty samples in the packaged demo application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some quick exmple of chart with select list

1.Create chart. Here is my query where :P9999_NEW is select list with departments.

```
select null,EMP.SAL as SAL,
EMP.DEPTNO as DEPTNO 
from EMP EMP
where EMP.DEPTNO = :P9999_NEW
```

[image]
2.Create select list to display departments name and return depart. number.

```
select DISTINCT(DEPT.DNAME) as DNAME,
EMP.DEPTNO as DEPTNO 
from EMP EMP,
DEPT DEPT
where EMP.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO
```

3. Add Change Dynamic action to refresh chart region after change values in select list. :P9999_NEW is the name of my Select list
[image][image]
[image]
You can add more select lists, just don't forget to include them in WHERE clause of query and in Item(s) change dynamic action.
I hope this can help you.